# react-native start "hot reloading" not working anymore on linux/ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native, watchman

i just started working with react-native a few days ago and everything went well so far. I dont know since when exactly but recently the "hot reloading" functionallity stopped working.

When i apply some changes to my code i see the app showing the "hot reloading..." message but the packager does not show anything.

When i double press "r" (emulator) or shake the device and press reload (native device) it will be refreshed and the packager shows "Bundling `index.js`..." - so baseically the packaging works, watchman seems to work too.

when executing "watchman watch-list" it displays my react-native root folder.

I think watchman is working and the app is requesting the new packaged source but for some reasing the packaging server is not rebuilding unless i double press "r" or shake the device.

So ONLY the "hot reloading" seems to be broken...

I tried reinstalling watchman (from source), no changes.

react-native info tells:

```
Environment:
  OS:  Linux 4.10
  Node:  7.10.0
  Yarn:  1.2.1
  npm:  4.2.0
  Watchman:  4.9.0
  Xcode:  N/A
  Android Studio:  Not Found

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.0.0-beta.5 => 16.0.0-beta.5
  react-native: 0.49.3 => 0.49.3
```

gradle is activated

Android Studio is installed too, i dont know why react-native cant find it but i dont think this is the problem.

**One sidenote that may matter:**

Once i start the android emulator (`$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/emulator -avd $DEVICEID`) my interface (ubuntu) gets extremely slow and unresponsive, changing the application with `[alt]+[tab]` only works with a delay of more than 500ms. Also focusing another window will take its time. My hardware cant be the issue (Intel i7 7th gen, 16gb ram, nvme ssd)...

Comment: i had the same issue

Comment: Could you solve it? If possible provide a solution, i would be very happy about it :-) If not you could upvote the question, so it gets more attention